# Buying a house: Is it a problem if I switch jobs after qualifying for a mortgage but before closing on it?

Tags: mortgage, job-offer

Lets say I get started with the process of buying a house.  I sign the sales paper and then secure a mortgage.  After I sign the sales papers and sign on for a mortgage, but before closing I get a new job.  Will I still be able to retain that mortgage I signed for, or will it all go to crap at closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in this situation now.  My realtor stressed that I should not change jobs until after we closed on the house, specifically because it could affect out ability to get a loan.

The loan (and consequently the mortgage and house) are not in your hands until closing.  Wait to change jobs until after you have closed on the house.

Comment: i would think in this market you probably need to show at least couple of paychecks. So definitely will be an issue.

Comment: Most loans have a stipulation that you have to get re-approved for the loan if you change jobs during the mortgage process. You're best off to wait to change jobs until after you close, but it *is* possible to change jobs, it could cause huge headaches and some delays with the mortgage however.

Answer (score 3):

There is more risk in changing jobs before closing.   That being said, your new job vs. your old job is also a consideration.

If you are staying in the same role (accountant at old job, accountant at new job), with a similar company, making the same or more money, you *should* be able to re-qualify with your new job.

If you change careers (accountant to house-painter), switch from W-2 to self-employed, change from full time to part time, it is likely to make getting approved very difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on timing. If your mortgage is already approved, there should be no issue. Do you have an obligation / contract to inform the bank about your change? My guess is that doesn't exist.

Banks typically look at your stability as a person. You've been working a number of month / years at your current job. Your new job is 'better' (higher salary). The bank doesn't care.